# Check characters in string

Tags: c++, string

I have a basic problem that I wanted to do where I'm trying to check whether a string contains lowercase or uppercase letters. I played around with `islower()` and `find()` but I'm not getting the desired results.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str1 = "";
    cout << "Enter phrase: ";
    getline(cin, str1);

    // Using islower()
    if (!(islower(str1)))
    {
        cout << "No lowercase character found.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Lowercase character found.";
    }

    /* *************************************** */

    // Using find()
    string lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    // string upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    if (!(str1.find(lower)))
    {
        cout << "No lowercase character found.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Lowercase character found.";
    }

    // Repeat for uppercase letters

    return 0;
}
```

Using `islower()` doesn't work because it seems to be expecting a `char` instead of a `string`. With `find()`, my test output always defaults to "Lowercase character found." Also, I've tried `string::find_first_of()` in place of `find()` but the results were not good either. Wouldn't either of these last two mthods check the string character by character until either lowercase or uppercase is found as defined in the `if` statements? I'd appreciate it if someone could please shed some light on this for me with an example.

Comment: The idea is to check the string `char` by `char`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to use the for-loop to check the string char by char

```
bool hasLower = false;
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++) { 
   if(islower(str1[i]) { //a lowercase char is found
      hasLower = true;
      break; //stop the for-loop
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `int` , use `string::size_type`  or `auto`

Comment: Thank you for answering. So I see that's one way of doing it. Wouldn't `find()` or `string::find_first_of()` as I mentioned above search the string char by char until it finds either lowercase or uppercase as specified in the condition?

Comment: @vishal is simply `size_t i = 0;`, `auto i = 0;` will give you an `int`. `string::size_type` pretty much *has* to be `size_t`.  No known exceptions and to reason *why* there would be.

Comment: Recommend against using `strlen` on a `std::string`. `str1.length()` should suffice.

Comment: @Blueshift, the way find works is that it is searching for the entire string "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" in str1. It is not looking for individual chars

Comment: Partially correct. `find` will look for the whole string. @Blueshift is right about  `find_first_of`, however. `find_first_of` [1) Finds the first character equal to one of the characters in str.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of). EDIT: `find_first_of` is a painful solution. Don't use it for this.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you for the comment. Out of curiosity, why would you say `find_first_of` is a painful solution?

Comment: @Blueshift You wind up iterating through two strings. Until you find a match, every character in the string you're testing will be compared against all 26 lowercase letters, resulting in about 26 times the work.

Answer (score 1):

[find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) is the function you should looking for. It breaks and returns the iterator when Unary function returns true. If no such element is found, the function returns last.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool check(char ch)
{

    if(islower(ch))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string str = "ApPLE";

    string::iterator it = find_if(str.begin(),str.end(),check);

    if(it!=str.end())
        cout<<*it<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"No lower case character"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `std::any_of`. It accepts a pair of iterator to denote the range in  `[iter1, iter2)` and third `unary function` as predicate to test each element in range.

It also has a clear name to represent **is any of element in [iter1, iter2) that matches the `predicate` function?**

```
bool has_lower(const std::string& str)
{
    return std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char c){ return std::islower(c); });
}
```

And it does as like the following:

```
while(iter1 != iter2) // search until meet the end
{
    if( predicate(*iter1) )  // check is_lower in char level
    { 
        return true; // early return if found
    } 
    iter1++;  // move to next character
}
return false; // not found
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no string-level function to check this condition. You should use islower() and isalnum() functions to check for those conditions for each character.

Comment: Please add some comments about your solution on why and how it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Paul, you can use `regex` to achieve the same.
Positive lookahead is what you want. The following regex does the trick:

```
^(?=.*[a-z]).+$
```

[See live demo](https://regex101.com/r/cC7rB1/1)

Note that this solution is limited to the ASCII-7 character set. If your input conforms to Unicode, this will not work.

Comment: ...limited to ASCII-7.

Comment: Even the input is.., I guess!

Comment: How do you figure the user-supplied input will be ASCII-7?

Comment: Nothing's mentioned by the OP. So I assumed it safely.

Comment: Well, that's the wrong way around of assuming anything, isn't it?

Comment: Not if the OP hasn't mentioned anything. Just added a statement in the answer to make the point clear :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96225/discussion-between-devsolar-and-happycoder).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do with `std::` regarding text, you are always at the mercy of the locale support of the host platform. And even in its latest incarnation, what you get from `std::` is simply not equipped to handle all aspects of Unicode.

(My favourite point in case is `std::toupper()`, which should convert the German lowercase `'ß'` to uppercase `"SS"`, but cannot because it *can* only return *one* character.)

There is basically only one library that *can* handle all aspects of Unicode, and **that is [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/)**.

Somewhat unfortunately, ICU4C (C/C++) is basically a port of ICU4J (Java), and therefore has a rather un-C++-like API. But trust me, if your code ever has to really *work* with text (as opposed to just "passing it through"), you will end up using the ICU library anyway, so why not get started with it right away?

```
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/uchar.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool hasLower( std::string str )
{
    // This converts str from the platform locale to
    // ICU's internal (UTF-16) encoding. You could also
    // *specify* the encoding of str explicitly.
    icu::UnicodeString ustr( str.c_str() );

    // Yes, ICU uses *signed* values here, and non-standard typedefs.
    int32_t length = ustr.length();
    for ( int32_t index = 0; index < length; ++index )
    {
        // Using char32At() and moveIndex32() instead of operator[]()
        // here so we work on code POINTS and not code UNITS (which
        // would fail for anything beyond the Basic Multilingual Plane).
        if ( u_islower( ustr.char32At( index ) ) )
        {
            return true;
        }

        index = ustr.moveIndex32( index, 1 );
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cout << "Enter phrase: ";
    std::getline( std::cin, str );

    if ( hasLower( str ) )
    {
        std::cout << "Lowercase character found.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No lowercase character found.\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile with (your platform's equivalent of) `-licuuc`.

Comment: Very interesting to read and learn about, will definitely be keeping it in mind. Thank you.